# How do I stop the auto-rotation on my website's slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a javascript issue, I believe.  I've been messing with the "duration" options, but that doesn't seem to do it.  Here is the url: http://www.compeat.com/services/index_sandbox.aspx

Comment: It would be better if you could post the javascript here...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the options of the used plugin: http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/options/ (e.g. switching off carousel options)

(I can second @vzait, next time, please post the code here..)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Galleria.get(0).pause()`